# What is the perpose of make option -r -R

Tags: makefile

From `make --help` Its status:

```
-r, --no-builtin-rules      Disable the built-in implicit rules.
-R, --no-builtin-variables  Disable the built-in variable settings.
```

when would I need to use these option? Sometime I do see people using both -rR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the built-in rules and variables is mostly for debugging purposes, although disabling the rules might improve performance in some cases.

Most "serious" makefiles out in the wild tend to declare their own rules and recipes for everything so the built-in rules are often superfluous. Disabling them *may* speed up execution of the makefile depending on how it's been written.

Say you have the following makefile along with a single file called `foo.cpp`

```
foo: foo.o
```

Make's debug dump for this is

```
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.o'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cc'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.C'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cpp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.p'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.f'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.F'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.m'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.r'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.s'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.S'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.sh'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.o'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.o'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.p'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.f'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.F'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.m'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.s'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.mod'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.c'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.c'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.y'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.y'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.l'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.l'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.w'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.w'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cc'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.cc'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.C'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.C'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.C,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.C,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.C'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.C'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.C'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cpp'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.cpp'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.p'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.p'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.web'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.web'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.web'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.web'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.f'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.f'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.F'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.r'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.F'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.F'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.F,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.F,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.F'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.F'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.F'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.F'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.r'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.r'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
     Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.F'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.m'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.m'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.ym'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.m,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.m,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.m'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.m'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.ym'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.ym'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.ym,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.ym,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.ym'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.ym'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.ym'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.ym'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.s'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.s'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.S'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.S'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.S'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.S,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.S'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.S'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.S'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.mod'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.mod'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cc'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.C'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.cpp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.p'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.f'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.F'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.m'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.r'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.s'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.S'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.sh'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.sh'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/Makefile.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 's.Makefile.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.Makefile.sh'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'foo'.
 File 'foo' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'foo'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo.o'.
 Found an implicit rule for 'foo'.
  Considering target file 'foo.o'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'foo.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo.C'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo.cpp'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'foo.o'.
    Considering target file 'foo.cpp'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for 'foo.cpp'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo.cpp'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo.cpp,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo.cpp'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/foo.cpp,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo.cpp'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/foo.cpp'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo.cpp'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.foo.cpp'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo.cpp'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.foo.cpp'.
     No implicit rule found for 'foo.cpp'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo.cpp'.
    No need to remake target 'foo.cpp'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo.o'.
   Prerequisite 'foo.cpp' is older than target 'foo.o'.
  No need to remake target 'foo.o'.
  Pruning file 'foo.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo'.
Must remake target 'foo'.
cc   foo.o   -o foo
Putting child 0x7fc4d94124c0 (foo) PID 1581 on the chain.
Live child 0x7fc4d94124c0 (foo) PID 1581 
Reaping winning child 0x7fc4d94124c0 PID 1581 
Removing child 0x7fc4d94124c0 PID 1581 from chain.
Successfully remade target file 'foo'.
```

Seems like a lot of work for something so trivial, although most of it is related to remaking the makefile and not the targets themselves. Still, this can all add up in a big project with lots of source files and makefiles.

Now have a look at the debug output for this file

```
foo: foo.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

invoked with `make -r`

```
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for 'Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile'.
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'foo'.
 File 'foo' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'foo.o'.
   File 'foo.o' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'foo.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'foo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'foo.cpp'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'foo.o'.
    Considering target file 'foo.cpp'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for 'foo.cpp'.
     No implicit rule found for 'foo.cpp'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo.cpp'.
    No need to remake target 'foo.cpp'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo.o'.
  Must remake target 'foo.o'.
g++   -c -o foo.o foo.cpp
Putting child 0x7fe1c0503520 (foo.o) PID 1614 on the chain.
Live child 0x7fe1c0503520 (foo.o) PID 1614 
Reaping winning child 0x7fe1c0503520 PID 1614 
Removing child 0x7fe1c0503520 PID 1614 from chain.
  Successfully remade target file 'foo.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo'.
Must remake target 'foo'.
g++    foo.o  -o foo
Putting child 0x7fe1c05038b0 (foo) PID 1618 on the chain.
Live child 0x7fe1c05038b0 (foo) PID 1618 
Reaping winning child 0x7fe1c05038b0 PID 1618 
Removing child 0x7fe1c05038b0 PID 1618 from chain.
Successfully remade target file 'foo'.
```

Not only do you now have complete control over the recipes, but you're also making things more efficient by specifying exactly what you need.

That said, if you find yourself cloning the built in rules exactly, you might consider instead simply disabling the rules you *don't* need with something like

```
$(MAKEFILE_LIST): ;
%.o: %.c
%.o: %.cc
%.o: %.C
%.cpp: ;
%: ;
```

As for the built-in variables I can't say I've found a use for `-R` other than debugging, keep in mind that `-R` already implies `-r` as the built-in rules are useless without the variables.